# How to capture group with regex Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

greetings for all you Jedi that can properly work with JS, I unfortunately cannot.

I want to iterate in all matches of the respective string '  m10  m20 m30 xm40', except the xm40, and extract the numbers, 10, 20, 30:

```
'  m10 m20 m30 xm40'.match(/\s+m(\d+)/g)
```

but this is what I get in chrome console:

```
'  m10 m20 m30 xm40'.match(/\s+m(\d+)/g)
(3) ["  m10", " m20", " m30"]
```

why is the 'm' being captured too? I just can't understand. I've tried a lot of combination without success. Any thoughts?

Bye!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `RegExp.exec()` function:

```js
const regex = /\sm(\d+)/g;
const str = '  m10 m20 m30 xm40';
let result = [];

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }        
    result.push(+m[1]);
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thx, I had found a single line saying that for iterate over groups is better to user RegExp.exec without explaining why. And only your code worked properly! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec 
I hate JS xD

Answer (score 1):

Another way of getting just those digits would be to match against `/\sm\d+/g` first, and then return the results of mapping over those results and extracting the digits.

```
var m = str.match(/\sm\d+/g).map(el => el.match(/\d+/)[0]);
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/2vy965jr/)**